# how to process parameters received from client in spring batch?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am studying Spring Batch, I need to write a rest api, here is the request body:

```
{

    "userId": "1",
    "userName": "Test"
}
```

`I don't know how the task can return this request and update the data for this user, I will be very grateful if you help:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class JobController {

    private final Job job;
    private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @PostMapping("/run")
    public ResponseEntity<UserAccount> runJob(@RequestBody UserDTO user) throws JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobParametersInvalidException, JobRestartException {
            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addString("userId", user.getUserId())
                    .addString("userName", user.getUserName())
                    .toJobParameters();

            jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);

            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

This batch config:

```
@Bean
public Job updateUserJob(Step updateUserAccount ){
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("updateUserJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(updateUser())
            .build();
}

public Step updateUser(){
    return  stepBuilderFactory.get("updateUser")
            .tasklet(((stepContribution, chunkContext) -> {
                List<User>  users = userRepository.findUserId(1);
                users.forEach(user -> user.setUserName("test"));
                userRepository.saveAll(users);
                log.info("finish {}", userRepository);
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            })). build();
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get access to job parameters from the `StepContribution` or `ChunkContext` objects provided through the `Tasklet`. Here is an example:

```
public Step updateUser(){
    return  stepBuilderFactory.get("updateUser")
            .tasklet(((stepContribution, chunkContext) -> {
                JobParameters parameters = stepContribution.getStepExecution().getJobParameters();
                String userId = parameters.getString("userId");
                String userName = parameters.getString("userName");
                // use job parameters as needed here
                List<User>  users = userRepository.findUserId(userId);
                users.forEach(user -> user.setUserName(userName));
                userRepository.saveAll(users);
                log.info("finish {}", userRepository);
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            })). build();
}
```